# Comportamiento bloque switch-case con operador OR

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estaba mirando código en los oscuros lugares de internet cuando me he encontrado la siguiente forma de utilizar los bloques en un switch.

```
input = -1;
switch(input){
  case 1: case -1:
    console.log("1 o -1");
    break;
   default:
    console.log("Default")
    break;
}
```

Nunca había visto esta forma de usar un `case` y se me ha ocurrido que sustituir los dos casos por un operador `OR` de la siguiente forma podría funcionar.

```
input = -1;
switch(input){
  case 1 || -1:
    console.log("1 o -1");
    break;
   default:
    console.log("Default")
    break;
}
```

Entiendo que si el input es `1` o `-1`, debería devolver true y entrar en el primer bloque, pero en caso de ser `-1`, salta al bloque por defecto.

**¿A qué se debe este comportamiento y por qué no es correcto?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La sintaxis de la sentencia case espera un único valor, tal como dice [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#syntaxis).

En tu pregunta pretendes comparar el parámetro del switch con diversos  valores del case, lo cual no es interpretado como tu pretendes, pues lo que hace el case es resolver ese OR para convertirlo a un único valor **antes** de ser ejecutado en la sentencia switch.

Si haces esto en javascript:

```
console.log(1 || -1)
```

verás que te devuelve 1, por eso solo funciona en ese caso.

Para usar condicionales dentro de las sentencias case, aún es posible, pero deben resolverse **antes** de ser comparados con el parámetro de la sentencia case.

En tu caso, esto podria ser una solución:

```
input = "1";
switch(true){
  case (input == "1" || input == "-1"):
    console.log("1 o -1");
    break;
   default:
    console.log("Default")
    break;
}
```

donde establecemos como parámetro un valor booleano **true**, y dentro del case hacemos la comparación de ambos posibles **input** con el OR, lo cual nos va a devolver true o false, permitiendo entrar en el case correspondiente o bien saltar al default.

Comment: No olvidar darle el +1 al OP, la pregunta lo merece.

Comment: @MauricioContreras hecho!  No acostumbro a hacerlo, la verdad, pues a veces la gente se precipita al hacerlo y luego el OP cambia la pregunta porque queria otra cosa, je, pero ya me fijaré más a partir de ahora, gracias.

Answer (score 6):

El comportamiento es el esperado, sucede que para cada bloque `case` debería usar una sentencia `break` que indica la salida o interrupción del `switch`, si no lo haces se ejecutará la evaluación del siguiente bloque.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const bad = (value) => {
    // switch sin usar break
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            console.log(`Foo: ${value}`);
        case -1:
            console.log(`Bar: ${value}`);
        default:
            console.log(`Baz: ${value}`);
            break;
    }
};

const values = [0, 1, -1];
values.forEach(v => bad(v));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se observa, al no incorporar o incluir la sentencia `break` se ejecuta el siguiente bloque de código independientemente de que no coincida con el caso dado. La sentencia `switch` busca el caso y empieza a ejecutar desde el primero que consiga dentro de los `case`, si no consigue ninguno, ejecuta la sentencia `default`.

Si ponemos la sentencia `break` el código se ejecuta correctamente:

```js
const good = (value) => {
    // switch usando break
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            console.log(`Foo: ${value}`);
            break;
        case -1:
            console.log(`Bar: ${value}`);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Baz: ${value}`);
            break;
    }
};

const values = [0, 1, -1];
values.forEach(v => good(v));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Sin embargo vemos que tanto para el caso 1 y -1, el bloque a ejecutar es idéntico, por lo cual podemos escribir:

```js
const better = (value) => {
    // switch sin usar break
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
        case -1:
            console.log(`Bar: ${value}`);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Baz: ${value}`);
            break;
    }
};

const values = [0, 1, -1];
values.forEach(v => better(v));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Y si lo quieres hacer un poco más evidente, entonces lo escribes tal como lo muestras en tu pregunta:

```js
const evenBetter = (value) => {
    // switch sin usar break
    switch (value) {
        case 1: case -1:
            console.log(`Bar: ${value}`);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Baz: ${value}`);
            break;
    }
};

const values = [0, 1, -1];
values.forEach(v => evenBetter(v));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**¿Porque `case 1 || -1` no funciona?**

En primer lugar hay que entender que la sentencia `switch ... case` hace una comparación del valor que tenga la variable pasada como argumento a `switch` con el valor declarado en  `case`:

```js
switch(value) {
    case 1: // si value === 1
       ...
       break;
    case -1: // si value === -1
       ...
       break;
    default: // si no es ninguno de los anteriores
       ...
}
```

Entonces, usar un `case` de este tipo: `case 1 || -1` siempre evaluará el caso cuando values es 1, porque el operador `||` es de cortocircuito, y devuelve el elemento de la izquierda si el mismo es evaluado a `true`, es decir, si el mismo es [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Eso quiere decir que `case 1 || -1:` siempre será igual a `case 1:` y nunca será igual a `case -1:`

Podemos verlo:

```js
const tooBad = (value) => {
    // switch sin usar break
    switch (value) {
        case 1 || -1:
            console.log(`Bar: ${value}`);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(`Baz: ${value}`);
            break;
    }
};

const values = [0, 1, -1];
values.forEach(v => tooBad(v));
console.log(`1 || -1 => ${1 || -1}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda. Agur!!!

Comment: Wow justo cuando creí que escribí una respuesta semi decente apareces tu con una respuesta infinitamente superior.

Comment: Y a una velocidad endiablada :-)

Answer (score 3):

El bloque `switch` compara el valor de cada `case` con `input`. No puedes usar operadores lógicos en un `case`. En el ejemplo que diste funciona con `input = 1` por una particularidad del operador `||`.

`1 || -1` es una expresión que evalua a `1` (porque 1 == true, entonces el operador `||` retorna el primer valor). Entonces la etiqueta queda como `case 1:`, por eso cuando pones `input = 1` entra a ese caso pero no con `input = -1`

Comment: Si que puedes usar operadores lógicos en un `case`, aunque parezca una cosa del averno, no tiene mucho sentido pero de poder se puede. Por otro lado decir que 1 == true es un poco impreciso, de hecho si sigo tu lógica, todos los números excepto el cero (0) son iguales a true. La palabra que buscas se llama [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy). En JS todos los valores se consideran `truthy` excepto 6: `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, y `NaN`. Saludos

Comment: A ver, que `1 == true` es truthy en sí mismo. Ahora `1 === true` eso sí es falso.

Comment: Y lo de que no se puede pasar operadores lógicos en el `case` era solo una simplificación. Me referería a que no puedes combinar dos casos en 1 como quería el OP.

Comment: @Fedex7501 Siempre puedes editar tu respuesta para aclarar eso que acabas de decir... los comentarios no siempre se leen

Comment: No olvidar darle +1 al OP, la pregunta lo merece